# stereo image proc bypass

Tags: calibration, camera1394, image-proc, viso2, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Ubuntu 14.04
ROS Indigo Igloo
Bumblebee2
```

Hello!

I am using a lookup table to rectify the images extracted with [camera1394stereo](http://wiki.ros.org/camera1394stereo) generated outside ROS with triclops. Now I have the "perfect" rectification but I want to bypass the stereo image proc to avoid the process of rectification, normalization and rotation.

I just want to generate the disparity image and the PointCloud2 image to use it in [viso2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros). The problem is that I don't have the correct parameters to fill the camera_info msg left and right cameras. As long I understand, viso2_ros use image_proc to do all the process to generate rectified images.

Is there some way to use image_proc, stereo_image_proc or depth_image_proc to get the disparity image and the pointCloud without do the rectification?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193541/stereo-image-proc-bypass/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2014-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think even at a very high level, `image_proc` inherently deals with data from only one camera, thus can't produce the kind of information you're looking for. You NEED to process data from multiple information sources to obtain disparity and pointcloud data, which is what `stereo_image_proc` and `depth_image_proc` are designed to do.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0